# Spartacus Layout for header unable make it empty Spartacus 3.2.2

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Initially I am trying to make empty slots for header, footer and landing page where I am able to achieve with footer and LandingPage2Template but not for header(I have gone through documentation which mentioned same for header I have gone through layout config from https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/page-layout/). Below is my code.

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
      layoutSlots: {
        header: {
          slots: []
        },
        footer: {
          slots: []
        },
        LandingPage2Template: {
          slots: []
        },
      }
    } as LayoutConfig)

Please let me know If I miss any config for header
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
header: {
  lg: {
    slots: [],
  },
  slots: [],
},
```